# Signing issue building using a bot

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm setting up a CI machine and the problem I'm facing is that the build fails with a profile/signing error when built using the bot.

However if I manually clone the project onto the CI machine and build it manually from within XCode on the build machine then it is successful - this shows that the CI machine's keychain is correctly set up and the profiles/signing setting of the project are all ok.

That fact that I can manually build it on my dev machine and on the CI machine but not using the bot suggests to me that the bot is running as a different user?

So my question is how do I set up the X Code server account / bot to be the correct user? The Apple Xcode CI document isn't very clear on this area, I've followed the instructions for configuring the server, configuring the bot, adding  group members to the XCode server etc. but something must have been incorrectly configured. Trouble is I've followed the documentation step by step but don't know where I could have gone wrong.

Anybody know of a good alternative bot tutorial as an alternative to Apple's documentation or have an idea what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the relevant provisioning profiles from

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles
```

to

```
/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/ProvisioningProfiles
```

and it'll build fine.
You might need admin permission to access that folder, though.

And if that doesn't work, copy the relevant certificates/private keys from the login keychain to the System keychain.

Comment: Doesn't work.  It looks like you need to copy keys from the user's keychain to the server keychain, that's if you can log into the build server and build successfully using Xcode (if you you need to export the keys from the development machine to the build server).

Comment: On our Xcode Server (Xcode 6), the destination directory was `/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles`.  We also had to ensure that *Allow all applications to access this item* was enabled for the keys in Keychain Access > (key) > Get Info > Access Control.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this is because..Xcode only downloads provisioning profiles that are managed by Xcode, which are the Team Provisioning profiles.

So you would only need to copy the ones that are not managed, like Adhoc Distribution profiles, and other custom provisioning profiles that are not created by default after creating a new Application ID.